# PHP - Login to another website, perform search and retrieve results

Tags: php, asp.net, html, curl

Hi I am developing a website and one of its features is to be able to log in to a website, and perform a search. The search results would then get sent back to me and I can use them in my page. To make this clearer, I have an image of the form from the website that I want to perform a search. Here is picture:

[[[image: imagebam.com]][3](http://www.imagebam.com/image/24d7af210938187)](http://www.imagebam.com/image/24d7af210938187)

Basically once I login, it arrives at that page. I then want to search for an ISBN. The results are instantly shown in the correct boxes. I want to take those results and then be able to use it in my website. I have been searching into using cURL but im not sure how to login, search and retrieve all in one go. I am also not sure how to receieve each result seperatley such as title, author etc as I want to display them in different parts of my page. If it helps, the website I need to get data from uses .aspx for both login form and search page

Comment: I do think you should search Google for [Screen scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping) or [Web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Comment: I have looked into it but I dont know how I can login, search and retrieve all in one go

Comment: Firstly you should check if you're allowed - most websites prohibit it - it's 'bandwidth fraud' amongst other things. Secondly it will involve keeping track of session cookies because it's definitely going to be 3 requests.